# How to capture iterated json values into a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cypress

Problem: I would like to store data into a json file with dynamically changing fields.
Let's say I would like to generate the following `invoice.json` file:

```
{
 "token": "000",
 "invoices":
 [
  {
   "invoiceId": "0001-0001-0001-0001",
   "amount": 45.67
  },
  {
   "invoiceId": "0002-0002-0002-0002",
   "amount": 11.03
  }
 ]
}
```

I have the following commands in theory which I don't think is working (I simplified it for better understanding):

```
const tokenValue = "000"
let invoiceIdValue = ""
let amountValue = ""
for(let i=0; i<1, i++) {
 let data = {
  "token": tokenValue,
  "invoiceId": invoiceIdValue[i] // <- I don't know how to call the 1st index of the field
  "amount": amountValue[i]
 }
}
```

What is the most readable way to write this into the variable then eventually a file?
Note: I will be using cypress' command `cy.writeFile('invoice.json', data)` to store the iterated values.

Comment: You want to create array of invoices and token is only once in expected json, So token should not be in loop

Comment: Sorry but that's not answering my question though. I included a fixed variable for demonstration purposes. I can use something like `cy.writeFile('invoice.json', { token: '000', Invoices[0]: data} )` but as I've said, that is not really my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your array of `invoices` first, then embed it in your data structure ...

```js
const tokenValue = "000";
let invoiceIds = [1, 2, 3];
let amounts = [10, 20, 30];

// Create invoices array first
const invoices = [];
for (let i = 0; i < invoiceIds.length; i++) {
  invoices.push({invoiceId: invoiceIds[i], amount: amounts[i]});
}

// ...then build data structure
const data = {token: tokenValue, invoices};

// Then save to file (or just log, as we're doing here)
console.log('invoice.json', data);
```

Comment: Thanks @broofa for this and I will upvote this. I think I oversimplified the problem though but hope you can still shed light on this: If I need dynamically changing values (instead of fixed value like in the array above), how would I be able to achieve this. For context, I am using faker & uuid (node) so I need to iterate too the values in amount (via faker.commerce.price()) and invoice id's (via uuid()).

Answer (score 0):

This is how, you can download your dynamic JSON as a file using javascript.

```js
var json = {
 "token": "000",
 "invoices":
 [
  {
   "invoiceId": "0001-0001-0001-0001",
   "amount": 45.67
  },
  {
   "invoiceId": "0002-0002-0002-0002",
   "amount": 11.03
  }
 ]
};

function downloadJsonFile(obj, fileName){
    var str = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute("href",     str);
    anchor.setAttribute("download", fileName + ".json");
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    anchor.remove();
  }
  
downloadJsonFile(json, "json_file_name");
```